# Custom Android Altimeter

Tags: android, progress-bar, customization

I've been trying to create a custom progress bar that can display the angle between two points. I have a circular progress bar adapted from ylyc's code (https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar), which works for setting the end point of the bar, but I want to develop this further to have a variable start point. Hopefully the image link may explain this clearer. I hope to use both points to visualise orientation data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNPtq.jpg

Comment: You can't have an angle between 2 points.  An angle requires  3.  Are you making the assumption that the points are always on the surface of the same circle, and the 3rd point is the center?

Comment: I have all the required data and the circular progress bar updating with one value (as variable2 increases, progress bar increases as expected). I would like to set a variable start position of the bar (so that the start point varies with variable1, in a similar manner to how the progress bar varies with variable2). This would then give me a dynamic representation of the two variables relation. I'm just not sure how to set up the variable start position.